# Equivalent model of a real inductor -2

Tags: inductor

Is this possible to explain what is happenning on this inductor?

[image]

[image]

I observed this phenomenon on an inductor. I simulate the phenomenon by adding a parallel resistor to the inductor, but I do not really understand what is happening into the inductor. It is like if it was saturating during the transient voltage applied to the inductance? Can someone tell me what is really happening physically?

Comment: (1) It is not clear what do you mean by "transient" voltage? Do you mean a step pulse? (2) It would be easier to so analysis if you are testing with a simple "sinusoidal" signal. (3) You need to understand some complex number stuff representing the model (in the phasor domain). (4) I would recommend to use a scope to calculate the inductance, to get a "real" picture of the phase angle etc.  (5) I use the following tutorial to do the real experiment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ajycdvKyCEw.

Comment: Is the red trace supposed to be inverted with respect to the blue trace?  Voltage going up with current going down doesn't seem correct.

Comment: Show the schematic. I see current of R2 but what's R2? And mark the nodes on the schematic to show which waveform is which.

Comment: That's the series resistance, and the difference between the peaks and the continuations (the "discontinuities", if you will) will give you its value. The same thing can be used to calculate the ESR in capacitors.

Comment: I do not think so as the current do not change its sign

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Saturation is a nonlinear phenomenon; it will not be modeled so simply.

The jagged triangle wave, consider the current through the two parallel paths of inductor and resistor.

The resistive current flows through effective parallel resistance around the inductor.  A typical case is a core made of resistive metal e.g. laminated iron, which acts in parallel by transformer action.

Comment: how do you explain the physical phenomenom ? How the inductor can saturate as the product of the voltage and the time is very low ? if it is a problem of saturation ?

Comment: It's not saturation. It's called "core loss".

Comment: This thé waveform I got from an oscilloscope. I do not think that thé core loss are causing a huge discontinuity on thé current ? Isn it ? If it is thé case how do you explain it ?

Comment: @Jess I don't know what you're asking/confused about. You drew a circuit, which models the measurement. I provided a name for the observed phenomenon. Is there a language barrier here, perhaps you could explain which words are being misunderstood?

Comment: I will close the subject and try to get the oscilloscope screen.